# Show exception message when debugging a property that throws an exception

Tags: c#

In the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A message from this exception...");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        var i = c.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

If you hover over `c` when debugging, you see the following:

[image]

Is there a way to show the actual exception message somehow?

Comment: I think if you let you debugger control go, it will break at throw statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring up the [QuickWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019) window (right-click on the variable while debugging and select QuickWatch on the context menu) and expand the property:

[image]